# Change cursor image

Tags: css, attributes, cursor

I set a cursor image with css:

```
#scroll_up{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 960px; 
    height: 300px; 
    cursor: url(../imgs/cursor_up.png), auto;
}
```

This style is applied to a div so that when I rollover this div I see the cursor as an image:

```
<div id="scroll_up">...</div>
```

I wrote a function in order to change the cursor image after N loops:

```
$("#scroll_up").css({ cursor : "url(imgs/cursor_down.png)" });
```

But it's not working...
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you start with `../` in the `cursor_up.png` URL and that is missing in the switch to the `cursor_down.png` cursor?

Comment: That's because the first part of the code is a css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$("#scroll_dwn").css({ "cursor" : "url(imgs/cursor_up.png), auto" });
```

The "auto" at the end makes the difference.
Hope it helps!